# cin.ignore() is producing undesired behavior

Tags: c++, getline, flush

For the following code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        getline(cin,s);
        cout << s << "\n";
        cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:

> 2
>
> Name1
>
> Name2

Expected output:

> Name1
>
> Name2

Error output:

> Name2 // followed by blank line

I don't know why is it happening. I tried all the solutions given on stackoverflow but unfortunately none worked for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the call to `ignore`. It's eating the next line. If you don't understand why, **read the specification** for `std::basic_istream::ignore`.

Comment: Removing `ignore` also not producing the expected output.

Comment: Off topic: Careful with `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` It's not saving you much work, it's non standard (so it only works on a single compiler) and combined with `using namespace std;` it's exposing you to some unnecessary risk.

Comment: The second problem is `cin >> t;` does not consume the new line that represents you pressing enter when typing in your input. This newline gets consumed by the first `getline` and results in an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.ignore()` is used to ignore the new line after inputting an integer.
So,use `cin.ignore()` after `cin>>t`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cin.ignore();
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        getline(cin,s);
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```